# Detect line/code of JAXB cyclic error

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I'm doing a project which uses JAX-RS and JPA, the entity classes were generated using Netbeans and because the classes are so big and generated cyclic errors happened.

My question is there a way to detect the offending code/line of the cyclic error? JAX-B error message are not so specific.

Comment: I don't really get it: don't you need to know your model at some point? If you only need to know a subset of the whole model, why don't you only implement that subset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to view the Object Graph JAXB analyzes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280626/is-it-possible-to-view-the-object-graph-jaxb-analyzes)

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - Exactly what I'm experiencing. Thanks.